# Allow user to manually exit out of Guided Access when it was started programmatically

Tags: ios, ios8, mdm, guided-access

Thanks for trying to help me out. My app calls

```
UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession ( BOOL enable, void (^completionHandler)(BOOL didSucceed) );
```

to start Single App mode. So far that's working great. However, it seems that the only way to get out of Single App mode after that point is if the app itself calls the same function again -passing 'NO' this time for the 'enable' parameter- to exit.

I'd like to set it up in a way that someone who administers the device can exit Guided Access in exactly the same way they would if they had started it manually (clicking the home button 3 times and entering passcode). Because let's say a connectivity problem happens before the app reaches the point where it ends the Guided Access session programmatically, someone needs to be able to get out of the app temporarily to troubleshoot the issue. So what I want is:

Start guided access programmatically  --> be able to end it manually

Is that possible? May be through a key in config profile? A delegate method that asks if user can do that? A setting on the device? If not, at the very least is there a notification that the user has attempted to exit guided access or clicked a hardware button?

I tried only on iOS 8 which is my primary focus.

Again thank you! Your help is very much appreciated.